# insert double quotes around selected text in xcode

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode, macros, code-snippets

Is there a keystroke to add double quotes around a selection in xcode?

I have snippets `@"<#string#>"` (qt) and `@"<#string#>"<#, #>` (qtc)(for making a list in array I use keystroke qtc+enter  word tab enter qt+enter...) that I use when I am typing, but I also could use some sort of a macro that I could highlight the word, tap a keystroke, and it would add @"" around it.  It seems a little easier. Once you enter the first qtc then you just need qt enter to get the next one from the code popup.

Is there a macro that would put the quotes around the current word the cursor is on? I have seen something like this in TextMate.

This would be a little convenience that would be nice when I am adding a list of words to an array or something and putting the quotes around all the words.

Maybe a little javascript to put in a webpage that would loop though and put the quotes each word in a list would be useful.  Or better yet an applescript or some sort of macro that could be used in xcode that would loop through words in a selection and add @"", around each word that could be triggered with a keystroke.  Then you could just type a list and select it and tap a keystroke and you just saved a ton of typing.

I found this applescript that replaces text webpage:

http://foolsworkshop.com/applescript/2008/05/an-applescript-replace-text-method/

If you use that you can use applescript with a list separated by commas copied to the clipboad:

`set theText to the clipboard`

`set theReplacedText to replaceText(", ", "\",  @\"", theText)`

`return theReplacedText`

then copy the results to the clipboard and paste them where you want.  I'm not sure how to get it to activate with a keystroke and replace the selected text a little more neatly.

Answer (score -1):

Is it not the same as in other languages like so NSString *string = @"Some text here /"Here is the text/" ";